# jquery dynamic added row display price form db on each row select option

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui

Hi i need some help in jquery task, i created table with dynamic row add. i want when i select option value this price display in this row next column, ever select option value will be different in each row

[image]

my code is here

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
$(".name").change(function()
    {
    var id=$(this).val();
    var dataString = 'id='+ id;

    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data)
        {
            $(".price").val(data.price);
            return false;
        } 
   });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      select item
    </th>
    <th>
      price
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <td>
      <select name="item[]">
        <option value="1">
          item name
        </option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <input type"text" name="price[]">
    <td>
    </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you paste your HTML too?

Comment: <table><tr><th>select item</th><th>price</th></tr><tbody><td><select name="item[]"><option value="1"> item name</option></select></td><input type"text" name="price[]"><td></td></tbody></table>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the picture it looks like you *would* several dropdowns with textbox next to it and you want to load the price of each item separately, for that you need to do things:

1. Change

   `$(".name").change(function()`

   to

   `$("select[name^='item']").change(function()`

   This means to target a `select` tag which has name starting with *item*.
2. Change

   `$(".price").val(data.price);`

   to

   `$(this).closest('tr').find("input[name^='price']").val(data.price);`

   This means we find the closest `tr` tag of the `select` and then find an `input` with name starting from *price* **within** the `tr` tag, so your select dropdown value always get stored in the next textbox.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3g3j7/)** (This link is just to give you an idea of how it works and AJAX is commented because JSFiddle  will not run it).

Answer (score 1):

With, dynamic rows, you should use `.on` method. Adding some classes to the elemens for esealy find them.

This code should work:

```
<table id="unit-price">
   <tr>
      <th>
         select item
      </th>
      <th>
         price
      </th>
   </tr>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <select class="name" name="item[]">
               <option value="1">item name</option>
            </select>
         </td>
         <td>
            <input type="text" class="price" name="price[]">
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
    $("#unit-price").on('change', '.name', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "test.php",
            data : {
                id : $this.val()
            },
            cache : false,
            dataType : "json",
            success : function (data) {
                $this.parent()
                    // Get parent tr
                    .closest('tr')
                    // Then, find price textbox with class 'price'
                    .find('.price').val(data.price);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: +1 I forgot the `.on`. @OP you should use this `change` method if you have dynamic dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could solve your problem using jQuery's [nextUntil()](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) function.

In your case, you could call `$(this).nextUntil(".price").val(data.price);`

I'm not too sure on this one so let us know if this works.